# How to configure my docker-compose.yml, specifically the API_BASE_URL?

Tags: docker-compose, blazor

I'm trying to deploy my web app locally on my computer. My web app is created with Blazor and I'm using docker to deploy. I'm having trouble understanding what the `API_BASE_URL` is. Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./api.Dockerfile
    environment:
        - DBNAME=my_db
        - DBADDR=localhost
        - DBUSER=my_user
        - DBPASS=password
        - SECRET=my_first_app
  blazor:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./web.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      - API_BASE_URL= "what to type here?"
```

Also, my .env in my api-folder is defined as:

```
DBNAME=my_db
DBADDR=localhost
DBUSER=my_user
DBPASS=password
SECRET=my_first_app
```

And my .env in my blazorServer, I do not know what to include here:

```
API_BASE_URL= "what to type here?"
```

And I can access my web app on: http://localhost:3000/

So basically, my question is how to define the `API_BASE_URL`? (My first time deploying a web app)

I tried to define `API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/api`, but when I deployed and accessed my web app on http://localhost:3000/ and tried to log in with username and password stored in my database, but I got an error:

--> Sending HTTP request POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/login

--> Cannot assign requested address (localhost:3000)

If I understand correct, the web app makes a request to the API, who retrieves the username and password from the database and then sends it back to the web app, right?